# Split column values based on delimiter and matches with another column in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

I have a following columns in a table in postgres schema.

```
ID              feature                    start         end
EBI-15947845    p.C29S                     29            29
EBI-15983374    p.E283C                    283           283
EBI-16057637    p.[L44D;A47D;I66D;L67D]    66            66
EBI-16057637    p.[L44D;A47D;I66D;L67D]    47            47
EBI-16057637    p.[L44D;A47D;I66D;L67D]    44            44
EBI-16057637    p.[L44D;A47D;I66D;L67D]    67            67
EBI-2266598     p.D1305_D1306delinsKK      1305          1306
```

I would like to transform the 'feature' column such the entry matches the value with start and end column. For more clarity, below are my desired columns after transformation.

```
ID              feature     start        end
EBI-15947845    p.C29S      29           29
EBI-15983374    p.E283C     283          283
EBI-16057637    p.I66D      66           66
EBI-16057637    p.A47D      47           47
EBI-16057637    p.L44D      44           44
EBI-16057637    p.L67D      67           67
EBI-2266598     p.D1305_D1306delinsKK      1305          1306
```

I can think of an approach but not able to implement it. The column value should be split by ; and then apply regular expression match on each component using start/end values and pick and replace when it encounter a match and concatenate with **p.**.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What if `start` and `end` have different values?

Comment: @GMB It will remain as it is in the final table. I have added a row at the end of the table for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you actually need to split the values. As far as I can tell, using [`regexp_match()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) should be enough:

```
select id, 
       case 
         when start = "end" and feature like 'p.[%' 
           then 'p.'||(regexp_match(feature, '([A-Z]'||start||'[A-Z])'))[1] 
         else feature
       end as feature,
       start,
       "end"
from the_table
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fa3dde6a4cad09b25b2bb816691f7519)

Comment: Thats perfect!!  Could you please explain the purpose of adding [1] ?

Comment: @rshar: because `regexp_match()` returns an array.